# Laravel Filament: How to save data to related model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

The model Employee is related to the model Detail which contains addresses and phone numbers for each employee. There is a form in the Employee Resource which contains fields both for the employees and the details tables. How can I save data to the Detail model from this form?

In the form function in the Employee Resource, I tried to use dot notation, but data is not saved.

```
                Card::make()
                    ->schema([
                        TextInput::make('detail.email')
                            ->email(),
                        TextInput::make('detail.mobile'),
                    ])->columns(2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add another step. Assuming you've already define the `detail` relationship in your `Employee` model, go to your `CreateEmployee` page and add this override method `handleRecordCreation` as below:-

```php
namespace App\Filament\Resources\EmployeeResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\EmployeeResource;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\CreateRecord;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CreateEmployee extends CreateRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = EmployeeResource::class;

    protected function handleRecordCreation(array $data): Model
    {
        $record =  static::getModel()::create($data);
        $record->detail()->create($data['detail']);

        return $record;
    }
}
```