# How do I add data to two tables in one form submission using filamentphp?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

This is the scenario:
I have two tables i.e Student and Guardian. They all have one form as stated below
[image: The Form]

I want when the form is submited. It creates a student gets the student Id and also adds the guardian data along with the student id.

The relationship between the student and guardian is a hasMany Relationship.

Comment: When you click on the student from the listing, then it will show the guardian details, right?

Comment: Not really, My desire is to enter the student and parent data at once though both are stored in different tables. 
The parent table stored the student id. 

so when creating the student the id is captured and passed as a variable while creating the guardian/parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the resource pages path of the form (app/Filament/Resources/YourResource/Pages/Create***.php)

and follow this code structure

```
<?php
namespace App\Filament\Resources\StudentResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\StudentResource;
use Filament\Pages\Actions;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\CreateRecord;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Guardian;


class CreateStudent extends CreateRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = StudentResource::class;`

    protected function handleRecordCreation(array $data): Model
    {
        //insert the student
        $record =  static::getModel()::create($data);

        // Create a new Guardian model instance
        $guardian = new Guardian();
        $guardian->first_name = $data['guardian_fname'];
        $guardian->last_name = $data['guardian_lname'];
        $guardian->gender = $data['guardian_gender'];
        $guardian->email = $data['guardian_email'];
        $guardian->contact_no = $data['guardian_contact'];

        // Assuming 'student_id' is the foreign key linking to students
        $guardian->student_id = $record->student_id; 

        // Save the Guardian model to insert the data
        $guardian->save();


        return $record;
    }
}
```

Notice that you have to import the Model of the second table and create an new instance then map each field to the corresponding data, By default all form entries in filament are stored in the $data array.

Comment: The solution is based on the answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75618155/laravel-filament-how-to-save-data-to-related-model)

Comment: I am using relationship() on repeater form input and not able to get those data in $data can you help me in this

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem. You can customise the `CreateAction` in `getActions()` method by using `using()` method on `Filament\Pages\Actions\CreateAction` like this.

```php
protected function getActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Actions\CreateAction::make()
                ->using(function (array $data): Model {
                    $student = static::getModel()->create($studentData);
                    $student->guardian()->create($guardianData);

                    return $student;
                }),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: I tried this out but it was not of help

Comment: I appreciate your help and it played a key foundation to me understanding the tasks ahead